# Await/Async Cross-thread calls?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm learning about async/await and is trying to incorporate them to my code, since some operations have a slight to significant affect on the UI.

In Form1 class I have an:

```
Private Async Sub Populate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Await Task.Run(Sub() PopulateGrid(query, dgv, {Button1, Button2}))
End Sub
```

`PopulateGrid` is in another class, along with similar methods:

```
Public Shared Sub PopulateGrid(query as DataTable, dgv as DataGridView, menuButtons() as ToolStripButton)
    Try
        dgv.DataSource = query
        ...

        ...
    Finally
        SetMenuButtonStates(dgv.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing, menuButtons)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error is on the `SetMenuButtonStates`, since that again is in ANOTHER class, raising a cross-thread exception...

What do I do?

Comment: Well yes, you're calling `Task.Run`, so that's going to execute `PopulateGrid` on a non-UI thread. You should quite possibly make `PopulateGrid` an async method instead - carefully - and then just call it from `Populate`.

Comment: You should grab data from UI, await on a background function which processes the data, and then update UI with results in `Populate`. Currently your background function touches too many things in UI which must be modified.

Comment: I did that, and I understand I have to put the `Await Task.Run` on the `dgv.DataSource = query` bit?  It raises the exception on `dgv` since it's from Form1...

Comment: @LexLi, can you be more layman about that? Thanks :)

Comment: @AwonDanag there are tons of async/await samples around the internet echo what I said. This is not a place to "correct your code". Google "async await WinForms" and you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide your background work from your UI elements.

In particular, you're currently passing a `DataTable`, a `DataGridView`, and a `ToolStripButton` into the method called from inside `Task.Run`. You shouldn't send UI elements like `DataGridView` and `ToolStripButton` into a separate thread like that.

Instead, have your background thread *only* fill out the `DataTable`, and then have the UI thread use that data to manipulate the `DataGridView` and `ToolStripButton`.